# Angular2 Ionic2 :: ngFor add/remove UI update issue

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor

In my Ionic2 (Angular2) application, I have a data service encapsulating an array of items, and a page showing those items, along with buttons to allow adding more items to it.

```
export class Person {
  constructor(private _name: string) { }
  get name(): string { return this._name; }
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private _persons: Person[] = [new Person('A'), new Person('B')];
  get persons(): Person[] { return this._persons; }
}

@Page({
  template: `
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let person of dataService.persons">
        {{person.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button (click)="onClickAdd()">Add</button>`,
})
export class MyPage {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  onClickAdd() {
    this.dataService.list.push(new Person('New Person'));
  }
}
```

The list renders fine in browser and list manipulation works fine as well. However, when I deploy the application on my cellphone, I start facing the following issue:

The list renders fine, but when I add/remove an item from the list, the UI does not update. When I perform some other user action (navigating elsewhere, clicking a button, etc), then the UI updates to show the updated list.

I will reiterate that I don't face this issue while testing in the browser. It only happens when I deploy the application on my Android device.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, and I'm out of ideas as to what I can try to troubleshoot/resolve this issue. =( Please help!

---

**EDIT**

Further testing reveals that the Ionic2 component `Alert` is to blame for this. More specifically, the way I'm using it. The `Alert` component allows the caller to call the `.dismiss()` method manually to close the dialog and returns a promise that is resolved when the transition is completed. I am modifying the list in this promise callback.

```
onClickAdd() {
  let dialog = Alert.create({
    message: 'Are you sure you want to add a new person?',
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Yes',
      handler: () => {
        dialog.dismiss()
          .then(() => navCtrl.pop)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('UPDATING...');
            this.dataService.list.push(new Person('X'));
          });
      }
    }]
  });
  navCtrl.present(alert);
}
```

I can see that `UPDATING...` is printed out to the console. But the behavior is the same as before. The UI updates in browser, but not in device, unless some other UI action is performed (like clicking on a button or navigating elsewhere and back).

If I remove the `Alert` logic and simply add the new person in the `onClickAdd()` handler, it works fine in both browser and device.

Comment: Can you create a plunker with the code, so I can use that to create and run an Ionic 2 app in a device and debug it from Chrome tools? Or just edit your question and add all the .html and .ts files needed.

Comment: @sebaferreras.. unfortunately.. the codebase i have has too many files to be posted online.. but ill try to create a plunkr and revert back..

Comment: Try installing crosswalk and test it again.. if not than just check what error it returns (debug it in chrome on your PC via chrome://inspect)

Comment: can you try `public dataService: DataService`?